# How to use OpenLayers OSM-Layer with degrees instead of meters?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I have an OSM-Layer as a base layer. When I create a vector I have to define the coordinates in meter.
Is there a way to use degrees right a way without reprojecting them beforehand to meters?

```
var p0 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(13.39, 52.5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Transform on the fly, using the following code:

```
var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var p0 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(13.39, 52.5).transform(geographic,mercator));
```

Comment: Thanks but is there no way to set the EPSG:4326 projection to the map or the layer so that everything will work with degrees?

Comment: If you are using OSM layer, then the tiles are available only in EPSG:3857. If you want the map to be in EPSG:4326, then you cannot use the default OSM Layer in it.

Comment: So you say there is no way to use degrees with the OSM Layer when working with Features? I have to reproject everything manually.

Comment: @strangeoptics See my Update

Comment: When I use your first approach with the transform method the point is ontop berlin as supposed. When I use the second approach with the projection in the layer the point is some where close to the north pole far far away from berlin ;)

Comment: Use wfs.addFeatures(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(13.39, 52.5))) instead of wfs.features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(13.39, 52.5)))

Comment: Doesn't change the output. I give up an will use the transform method for every point :(

Comment: @strangeoptics: I rolled back the update, because as you have experienced, just setting the spatial reference on the layer does not work with manual Features. It works in other cases like using the WFS protocol, or using the KML protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the projection of your layer. OpenLayers will reproject it automatically for you.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate how to define it in OpenLayers. Might help the OP.

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe: has done it in his answer